# accidentally deleted collection in firebase - way to restore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am one of the cases that mixed up the browser windows and deleted the data in the wrong project.

I have deleted a collection in a firestore database. Is there any way to recover it? I have contacted support, but it may take a while. Up to 2 days :/
I have also seen that you can now set a paid backup. Activating the option incl. billing afterwards won't do much i guess ?

What I already did:
Contacted support, searched the net and crawled through the developer console.

EDIT:

Unfortunately you are right and support could not help me either.

**BUT** there is a solution and I leave it here for the next person who has the problem.
When something is deleted in firestore, it is a fight against time. By default you can go back one hour in each database. Doesn't matter if PITR has been enabled or not. @FrankvanPuffelen linked that part.

The easiest way is to open a cloudshell - because authentication is easier through it.
Start a console in the affected project.
Installs the SDK with "npm install firebase-admin" and get the data back with a transaction.

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

// don't know if necessary
admin.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: 'https://---projektID---.firebaseio.com'
});

const db = admin.firestore();
const colRef = db.collection("your collection");

goodtime = new admin.firestore.Timestamp(timestamp in seconds from past,0)

//readonly transaction
db.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
   const querySnapshot = await transaction.get(colRef);
   if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
      //got something here your code to export how you want
      firstDoc = querySnapshot.docs[0];
      console.log(firstDoc.data());
      console.log("timeStart:", data.timeStart);
    } else {
      console.log("nothing found, play with the timestamp");
    }
  },{
      readOnly: true,
      readTime: goodtime
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("ERROR:", error);
    });
```

Comment: Nope, if you didn't have a backup then the data is gone.

Comment: Going forward, you may want to consider configuring pPoint in Time Recovery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pitr), which was just launched and allows recovery of data in such cases.